# Error when Initialising an Array of Ellipse2Ds

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an array of Ellipse2D so I can later reset their positions in paintComponent(). It is not letting me initialise with an error under the Ellipse2D on line 3. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Ellipse2D[] ellipses = new Ellipse2D[1000];
for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){ 
    ellipses[i] = new Ellipse2D(2,2,2,2);
}
```

Comment: You should also post error detail!

Comment: What language is this? Java I guess?

Comment: You should choose i < 1000 instead of <= 10000

Comment: Thanks, that was a mistake, but unfortunately did not fix the problem.

Comment: Ellispse2D is an abstract class, right?

Comment: You can only initiate  Ellipse2D.Double or Ellipse2D.Float, not Ellipse2D itself

Comment: I am quite a new programmer and unfamiliar with the term 'abstract'

Comment: An abstract class is meant to be extended by other class. It basically contains common properties and methods needs by a bunch of other subclasses which shares the same properties and methods.

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot! If you want you can submit that as answer and I will like it, I don't know if that is what is support to happen or not though.

Answer (score 1):

From the Java [document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html):

> public abstract class Ellipse2D extends RectangularShape
>
> The Ellipse2D class describes an ellipse that is defined by a framing
>   rectangle.
>
> This class is only the abstract superclass for all objects which store
>   a 2D ellipse. The actual storage representation of the coordinates is
>   left to the subclass.

And the following constructor definition:

> protected     Ellipse2D() This is an abstract class that cannot be
>   instantiated directly.

The above documentation makes it clear that the Ellipse2D class cannot be initiated. An abstract class is meant to be extended by other classes. It basically contains common properties and methods needs by a bunch of other subclasses which shares the same properties and methods.

For Ellipse2D, it contains two nested subclasses (nested means the subclasses are defined inside Ellipse2D itself) which are  Ellipse2D.Double and Ellipse2D.Float. You can initiate either of it and if you like assign it to Ellipse2D like this:

```
Ellipse2D[] ellipses = new Ellipse2D[1000];
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){ 
   ellipses[i] = new Ellipse2D.Float(2,2,2,2);
}
```